# Custom login in front of kubernetes dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I want to have a custom login page in front of the kubernetes dashboard. 
Is there a way to have it. I tried calling kubernetes dashboard

```
app.get('/loginsuccess', function (req, res) {
  return res.redirect(localhost:8001/ui);
})
```

but it returns HTML page with upgrade your browser as text. 
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You mean having a custom login page as in custom HTML/layout? Or custom authentication method?

Comment: My use case is, I have a login URL which takes redirection URL, which authenticates a user and returns to redirect URL with bearer token. I can keep token in the cookie and on expiry he will be redirected to login again. Which method do you think is good? Thanks